# How to convert git log --name-only in a specific format?

Tags: git

I would like to convert `git log --name-only` in a specific format.

Original output of `git log --name-only`:

```
commit 565ad47821a7e3e6c95304143530e5e355b32e72
Author: Yu-Cheng Ling <ycling@google.com>
Date:   Wed Dec 18 23:15:49 2019 -0800

    Override experimental_new_converter is not None.

    PiperOrigin-RevId: 286335164
    Change-Id: I66793be1e5277425f6da6dd519b256e18d61d071

tensorflow/lite/python/tflite_convert.py
tensorflow/lite/python/tflite_convert_test.py

...more commits
```

The desired conversion should look as follows:

```
Yu-Cheng Ling,tensorflow/lite/python/tflite_convert.py

Yu-Cheng Ling,tensorflow/lite/python/tflite_convert_test.py

...more
```

I have currently made several unsuccessful attempts in java programming language.
Maybe java is not the right programming language for this problem.

Any hints or tips? Or rather, how would you solve the problem?
Another query `git log --name-only --pretty=format:%an;` gives a near resultat, but not completely correct.

Could someone please help me?

Thanks

Additional:
git log --name-only --pretty=format:%an;

The output looks:

````
Yu-Cheng Ling;
tensorflow/lite/python/tflite_convert.py
tensorflow/lite/python/tflite_convert_test.py

A. Unique TensorFlower;
tensorflow/go/op/wrappers.go

TensorFlower Gardener;
Yunxing Dai;
tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/dynamic_dimension_inference.cc
tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/dynamic_dimension_inference.h
... more```



I still need to remove the line break and convert the output to:


-----------------------------------------------------------------
Yu-Cheng Ling,tensorflow/lite/python/tflite_convert.py

Yu-Cheng Ling,tensorflow/lite/python/tflite_convert_test.py

...more

-----------------------------------------------------------------
````

Comment: Can you tell us the problems you had with java?

Comment: What exactly was the problem with using `—pretty-format`?

Comment: The line breaks and the missing information before the file name. I have added informations in the initial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `awk` is for.

```
git log --name-only --pretty=format:%an \
| awk ' /^$/ { del name; next }
        !name{ name = $0; next }
             { print name","$0 }
'
```

or

```
git log --name-only --pretty=format:%an \
| awk '{ for (n=1; n++<NF; ) print $1","$n }' RS= FS=$'\n'
```

with whatever extra newline printing you want sprinkled in there.

Comment: sorry, my output looks like :

Comment: $ cat log.txt | awk '{ for (n=1; n++<NF; ) print $1","$n }' RS= FS=$'\n'
commit 565ad47821a7e3e6c95304143530e5e355b32e72,Author: Yu-Cheng Ling <ycling@google.com>
commit 565ad47821a7e3e6c95304143530e5e355b32e72,Date:   Wed Dec 18 23:15:49 2019 -0800
    Override experimental_new_converter is not None.,
    Override experimental_new_converter is not None.,    PiperOrigin-RevId: 286335164

Comment: If you run the awk on the output from a different command, it will give different results, yes.  Try running it on the output from the command shown.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are my hero!!! It works nice. Sorry, i can not give you a like, because i am new.